# Move leading or trailing whitespaces in string out of asterisks

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to transform invalid markdown for bold words into valid one. For the major part I've figured out how to get the words surrounded by asterisks but now I'm trying to find a way to transform this:

```
**A bold text **
```

Into this:

```
**A bold text**
```

Moving the trailing whitespace two steps to the right, out of the asterisks.

Same would be needed for leading whitespaces.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit:** I'd need to keep the whitespace but outside the bold syntax, not remove it.

Comment: "FE"?? .........

Comment: My bad. changed it to JS

Comment: Ah, okay. Tags don't go in titles. That's why we have tags. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let str = '**A bold text **';
let frontSpace = str.match(/\W{1,}/).toString().replace('**',''); 
let rearSpace = str.match(/\W{2,}$/).toString().replace('**','');

console.log(frontSpace + '**' + str.replace(/\*\*/g,'').trim() + '**' +rearSpace);
```

Comment: This is nice but I'd need to move that whitespace out of the asterisks, and now it's being removed instead. Example: hello there[WHITESPACE] into **hello there**[WHITESPACE]

Comment: @keelhauled ok I get you, I will edit the answer in a moment.

Comment: @keelhauled please check the modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace

```
\*{2}(\s*)([^*]+?)(\s*)\*{2}
```

[image]

```js
let str = `**A bold text **`

let replacer = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/\*{2}(\s*)([^*]+?)(\s*)\*{2}/g, (m, g1,g2,g3) => {
    return `${g1}**${g2}**${g3}`
  })
}

console.log(replacer(str))
console.log(replacer("some random string **  some text  **"))
```

Comment: This is nice but I'd need to move that whitespace out of the asterisks, and now it's being removed instead.

Example: **hello there[WHITESPACE]** into **hello there**[WHITESPACE]

Comment: Basically the whitespace should be kept but outside of the bold syntax

Comment: @keelhauled well there can be leading and trailing whitespace, which white space you want to place at which place ?

Comment: well for leading whitespace, it should be moved out of the asterisks, two characters to the left. and for trailing whitespace, out of the asterisks two characters to the right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of split and trim to build the expected string as shown below.

```
const word1 = '**  Hello Keel  **';

const wordArr1 = word1.split('**');

console.log(wordArr1[0] + '**' + wordArr1[1].trim() + '**' + wordArr1[2]);
```

This would also work for `Hello **  Keel  **, Welcome to Stack Overflow`

Comment: `Try this` is not really meaningful. And why do you repeat the same code twice? Only to illustrate that it will work with both `**  Hello Keel  **` and  `Hello **  Keel  **, Welcome to Stack Overflow`?

Comment: Sure, I am new to this so not really sure the comment should be. Thanks for your suggestion, I will take care going forward. To answer your question, yes just to illustrate I added two different example.

Comment: You should avoid code duplication because then it is not clear that those are identical codes, one could think that they are different due to the different patterns. Alternatively, to my edit you could wrap your code into a function to which you pass `word1` and `word2` and then return the result.